# Asus Zenfone cycling in the starting of charging process

Tags: recovery-mode, charging, fastboot

I have an ASUS ZenFone Max Pro (X00T/X00TD)

It is/was discharged and powered off. When i plug it in for charging, it is cycling in start of chaging:

1. vibration
2. the icon of empty battery
3. The bootloader is unlocked... text
4. the icon of empty battery
5. empty screen
6. and then starts again from vibration

I tried to clean the phone's connector, even wiped and stracthed the connector a littlebit, and  changed cable, charging source. (One cable is in the 1A charger, another cable is connected to PC.)  It doesn't get better.

I tried to leave it in the cycling, i hoped it gets some power.

**Does the phone charge always when connected to power, or it just start the charging process after it shows the charging animation (which i don't reach)?**

I tried to step in Fastboot mode. It stays in this mode, no cycling.

**Does the phone charge in fastboot mode?**

I tried to step in Recovery mode.

1. vibration
2. powered by android
3. The bootloader is unlocked... text
4. powered by android
5. empty screen and turns off

In fastboot mode i tried to flash stock recovery, and also TWRP and RedWolf recovery. The flashing process works, but i still cannot get in recovery mode, to see something more, maybe about battery or i dont know.

Of course the phone does not turn on. The same as when i try to get in recovery mode.

1. vibration
2. powered by android
3. The bootloader is unlocked... text
4. powered by android
5. empty screen and turns off

I did not do anything special nowadays with the phone. Bootloader unlocking and rooting was years ago, nor i did upgrade, so nothing special. I just used the phone, it discharged, and i'm in this state.

**What can i do?
Is it something with charging, or it has enough power after connected in fastboot mode, but the problem is something with the software?**

One more thing: maybe i "pressed" the buttons randomly in my pocket.

**Is it possible that in an unlucky situation i got into the recovery mode and pressed something away in recovery menu?**

Please help.

edit #1:

Is it possible to turn off the charging screen, charging vibration, screen turning on from fastboot mode? Maybe flash something on or similar? Because then it won't use the slowly charging power.

edit #2:

So the sumary now:

1. My phone is fully charged.
2. It does not boot into normal.
3. It does not boot into recovery, nor by hardware keys, nor by command from fastboot. I tried to flash TWRP, RedWolf and the original recovery too.
4. Fastboot mode works normally.

Parameters:

```
D:\Mobil>fastboot getvar all
(bootloader) CPU:SDM636
(bootloader) platform:sdm636
(bootloader) secret-key-opt:*censored*
(bootloader) build-type:user
(bootloader) unlocked:yes
(bootloader) off-mode-charge:1
(bootloader) charger-screen-enabled:1
(bootloader) battery-soc-ok:yes
(bootloader) battery-voltage:4286
(bootloader) version-baseband:       *this is empty, i didn't delete it*
(bootloader) version-bootloader:ZB601KL-0x01-20181019151150
(bootloader) variant:SDM EMMC
(bootloader) partition-type:cache:ext4
(bootloader) partition-size:cache: 0x15E00000
(bootloader) partition-type:userdata:ext4
(bootloader) partition-size:userdata: 0xCEB7FBE00
(bootloader) partition-type:system:ext4
(bootloader) partition-size:system: 0x100000000
(bootloader) secure:yes
(bootloader) serialno:*censored*
(bootloader) product:QC_Reference_Phone
(bootloader) max-download-size:536870912
(bootloader) kernel:uefi
all:
finished. total time: 0.031s

D:\Mobil>fastboot oem device-info
...
(bootloader) Verity mode: true
(bootloader) Device unlocked: true
(bootloader) Device critical unlocked: false
(bootloader) Charger screen enabled: true
(bootloader) Bootloader version: ZB601KL-0x01-20181019151150
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.016s
```

But:

```
D:\Mobil>fastboot boot stock_recovery.img
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  1.859s]
booting...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 1.859s
```

So booting failed. But i don't know why.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117011/discussion-on-question-by-trob-asus-zenfone-cycling-in-the-starting-of-charging).

Comment: @Firelord, how can we reach chat normally? I mean now i reach chat by your link. But normally how can we start chat?

Comment: Go to [chat]. Search for a user and invite them in. Create a chat room for them before that. It is all there in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not...

The solution was very stupid.

I cleaned the phone inside, especially the bottom part. Around the connectors, lot of dirt and drying moisture got in. Just enough for - probably - some short circuit.

I don't know why was it okay for fastboot mode, and not okay for recovery and normal boot.

Answer (score 1):

Good news!

This gets the voltage of the battery:

```
fastboot getvar battery-voltage
```

It says it's 4,32 V. If i remember right, this is around a fully charged battery. So probably it charged up when i left in Fastboot state for some hours. And the cycle/loop meant not that it cannot charge, but rather it does not need to charge.

Bad news!
Then what the heck is with my phone?

Comment: 3,85V is the rated voltage, it is written on the battery. (I disassambled the phone.) Charged voltage is higher, discharged voltage is lower.

Comment: can you figure pin-out? you can charge with some universal cell phone charger like this http://cgi.ebay.com/152786628220

Comment: Why do i need it? Battery is charged, and phone charges it also in Fastboot.

Comment: Do you think it writes a wrong number? Is that possible? Hm. I have been trying so long, it should be dead now, if it would not charged. I think.

Comment: See the origial post's end. I just edited it. It says "boot" command is unkown. And that is very strange.

Comment: idk but we are still talking about previously working device without any software updates which is dying because of low battery, not about boot-looping device with software issues, right? so if it isn't software issue it must be hardware failure

Comment: Sadly you are right. There is only one exception. Once when i get it out of my pocket, i saw the stock recovery screen. I said "reboot system", or similar. (To start normally.) But as i see pictures of others recovery menu, there is nothing i could do wrong with. The worst would be the factory reset, but then it should still start, without my datas.